# Plot encoding R

Tags: r, encoding

I worked on windows and I change to Linux. I would like to run my Rscript that I created on my windows cumputer to my Linux cumputer. When I run graphs, encoding is not good. I tried to create a html page. Title have a good encoding but not graphs. Do you have an idea to resolve my problem ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].